# React - Key press and move to component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

As a title: there is a way moving to components when pressed a key ?

For example:

- Click "Tab" and go to first row of my table;
- Click "Enter" and go to input.

I've tried use React reference but I have not succeeded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can use [react-use](https://github.com/streamich/react-use) library it gives you some hooks to perform actions. you can import useKey from form it like this

```
import useKey from 'react-use/esm/useKey'
```

And then later in functional component can write

```
useKey('Escape', ()=>{})
```

Now when you will press escape it will run the callback function. In that function you can write focus logic.

Remember to use useKey, Component must be a functional component as we can only use hooks in functional components

Comment: Second part is adding references (useRef) to the sections you want to focus. Some elements are not focusable by default, so you want to add tabIndex="-1" to them. -1 is so that they are not accessible by regular tab-behavior